# Open source android application for file storage?

Tags: open-source, file-management, encryption

Is there an open source Android application for photo/video file storage that have password? App should keep selected files in "vault" what mean file is encrypted, absorbed by app and finally deleted from default location. If someone care, app that I described is https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.domobile.applockwatcher&hl=en&gl=US but open source.

Comment: Maybe something like [Secure File Manager](https://f-droid.org/packages/com.securefilemanager.app/), which allows you to hide files and lock the app with a password? I haven't tried it myself, and your definition is rather vague, so I'm not sure if it would fit.

Comment: @Izzy thank for recommendation, I will check that app but I'll only edit qestion for now to be more transparent.